# ExpandableListView with an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView where each parentView has an EditText (and a textview) in it. When i added the EditText to the Layout it would no longer let me click or expand the ExpandableListView, all focus just goes to the EditText. Is there a way to make both the EditText and the ExpandableListView itself be clickable? I want to be able to click the expandableListView to expand the list, and the EditText to be able to enter text.

Thanks

**EDIT: added code of my group view**

```
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
        }

        TextView playerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playerName);
        playerName.setText(groupElements[groupPosition]);
        final EditText holeScore = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);
        holeScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(scoreCard.this, "On CLick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holeScore.setFocusable(true);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of EditText's default focusablitiy. Since they are capable of getting focused by default this will make your parent view to be unfocused. So what you have to do is  remove the focus capability of your EditText  by using,

```
andorid:focusable="false".
```

And similarly if you are having any button in your parent, setting focusable false to it also will help. This is the only way you can make your parent view to get clicked.

Comment: This allowed me to expand my list, but now when I click in the EditText the soft keyboard won't come up... How can I fix this?

Comment: you can use a click listener for your edit text and within that you can set the focusability to true, this will help you to get the soft keyboard.

Comment: I added an onClickListener, and the toast message came up so it is being called, but the keyboard still didn't come up.. I'm guessing i have to set the soft keyboard to a special state, but not sure which one...

Comment: Have you solved it?.i am facing same issue.if you got any solution then tell  me.

Comment: Any one have solution for this